# What are the Earths present in the modern Arrowverse?

Tags: dc, arrowverse

In the modern Arrowverse, what are the Earths which are present in 2021. I would like to know about the number of known Earths present in the present timeline of Arrowverse.

Comment: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/105534/what-are-the-different-universes-mentioned-in-crisis-on-infinite-earth

Comment: @Paulie_D that lists the pre-Crisis Earths, but not the post-Crisis Earths

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the [*Crisis on Infinite Earths*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crisis_on_Infinite_Earths_(Arrowverse)) story arc concluded in early 2020, there was only a small handful of Earths left remaining:

- Earth-Prime (main Arrowverse): *Arrow*, *Flash*, *Supergirl*, *Legends of Tomorrow*, *Black Lightning*, *Batwoman*, *Superman & Lois*
- Earth-2: *Stargirl*
- Earth-9: *Titans* web series
- Earth-12: *Green Lantern* film
- Earth-19: *Swamp Thing* web series
- Earth-21: *Doom Patrol* web series
- Earth-96: *Superman Returns* film

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DC_Multiverse_worlds#Earth-Prime_(Arrowverse))

Comment: Doesn't the DC Movie Universe technically also "exist" in the Arrow Multiverse? The two Barry Allens met, so at one point there was a connection.

Comment: @Josh per [this source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_Extended_Universe): "*However, despite [Ezra Miller's] cameo, the episode does not confirm the designated Earth for the DCEU characters.*"